# Getting undeclared Identifier errors in Winsock.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, networking, winsock, winsock2

I am trying to compile a code

```
#include <Header1.h>
#include "Header2..h" 
#include <ctype.h>
```

`Header1.h` includes `winsock.h` and `Header2.h` includes `windows.h`

I am using `winsock.h` instead of `winsock2.h` because `winsock2.h` was showing redefinition errors, which is a standard error, but I was not able to fix that using the solutions provided to them.

I have also tried including `ws2tcpip.h`, but it is giving tons of redefinition errors in `winsock.h`.

I am getting 12 errors in this Module

```
error C3861: 'close': identifier not found
error C2664: 'setsockopt' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'timeval *' to 'const char *'
error C2065: 'socklen_t' : undeclared identifier
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'optionLength'
error C2065: 'optionLength' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'optionLength' : undeclared identifier
error C2664: 'setsockopt' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'int32 *' to 'const char *'
error C2065: 'MSG_WAITALL' : undeclared identifier
error C2664: 'recvfrom' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'uint8 *' to 'char *'
error C2065: 'ERROR_END_OF_STREAM' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'close': identifier not found
error C3861: 'close': identifier not found
```

Comment: Can you share the piece of code that gives you errors?

Comment: I was getting  `error C3861: 'close': identifier not found` when compiling some C++ code using MSVS compiler. When renamed to `file.c` from `file.cpp`, it compiled fine, but adding `#include <io.h>` solved it and then the file complied as `file.cpp` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `#include <winsock2.h>` or `#include <ws2tcpip.h>` on the top of includes.

```
#include <winsock2.h> 
#include <Header1.h>
#include "Header2.h"
#include <ctype.h>
```

winsock.h should be included first. And I notice that your code seems to be unixish code. On windows, `closesocket` is used for closing socket.

Comment: Thanks mattn I added #include <ws2tcpip.h> and some errors are removed

Answer (score 3):

Also, #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before anything else.  That often helps.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in some cases helps this (issues with ws2tcpip identifier error):

```
#pragma once

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32.Lib")
```